# Issue with MS Excel macro adding colour to a bubbles in a bubble chart

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise Excel and am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nEOjcyGh1O0 to colour the bubbles in my bubble chart. The row "Ser.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)" is throwing the error "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method". How can I resolve this please?

[image]

```
Sub ChangePointColour()
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim Ser As Series
    Dim Pt As Point
    
    'Seect the chart
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
    Set Cht = ActiveChart
    Set Ser = Cht.SeriesCollection(1)
    PointCount = Ser.Points.Count
    
    For i = 1 To PointCount
        'Get the colour from column F
        ThisColor = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 6).Value
        Select Case ThisColor
            Case "Red"
                Ser.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Case "Green"
                Ser.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            Case "Amber"
                Ser.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForColor.RGB = RGB(255, 191, 0)
        End Select
        
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ForeColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.fillformat.forecolor) instead of ForColor.